# Gem conflict error

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, android-testing

I have automation tests that I run through RubyMine fails due to conflict error. Although it runs completely fine through the command line.
Following is the error:

```
Unable to activate aws-sdk-v1-1.67.0, because json-2.0.2 conflicts with json (~> 1.4) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

Also I am new to ruby so following is the list of gems:

```
actioncable (5.1.4)
actionmailer (5.1.4)
actionpack (5.1.4)
actionview (5.1.4)
activejob (5.1.4)
activemodel (5.1.4)
activerecord (5.1.4)
activesupport (5.1.4)
addressable (2.5.2)
appium_lib (9.6.1)
arel (8.0.0)
ast (2.3.0)
avro (1.8.2, 1.7.7)
awesome_print (1.8.0)
aws-partitions (1.21.0)
aws-sdk (1.67.0)
aws-sdk-acm (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-apigateway (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-applicationautoscaling (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-applicationdiscoveryservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-appstream (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-athena (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-autoscaling (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-batch (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-budgets (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-clouddirectory (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudformation (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cloudfront (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudhsm (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cloudhsmv2 (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudsearch (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudsearchdomain (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudtrail (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cloudwatch (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-cloudwatchevents (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cloudwatchlogs (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-codebuild (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-codecommit (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-codedeploy (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-codepipeline (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-codestar (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-cognitoidentity (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-cognitosync (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-configservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-core (3.5.0)
aws-sdk-costandusagereportservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-databasemigrationservice (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-datapipeline (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-dax (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-devicefarm (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-directconnect (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-directoryservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-dynamodb (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-dynamodbstreams (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-ec2 (1.7.0)
aws-sdk-ecr (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-ecs (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-efs (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-elasticache (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-elasticbeanstalk (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-elasticloadbalancing (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-elasticloadbalancingv2 (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-elasticsearchservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-elastictranscoder (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-emr (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-firehose (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-gamelift (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-glacier (1.4.0)
aws-sdk-glue (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-greengrass (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-health (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-iam (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-importexport (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-inspector (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-iot (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-iotdataplane (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-kinesis (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-kinesisanalytics (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-kms (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-lambda (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-lambdapreview (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-lex (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-lexmodelbuildingservice (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-lightsail (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-machinelearning (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-marketplacecommerceanalytics (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-marketplaceentitlementservice (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-marketplacemetering (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-migrationhub (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mobile (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-mturk (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-opsworks (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-opsworkscm (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-organizations (1.3.0)
aws-sdk-pinpoint (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-polly (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-rds (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-redshift (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-rekognition (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-resourcegroupstaggingapi (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-resources (3.1.0)
aws-sdk-route53 (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-route53domains (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-s3 (1.4.0)
aws-sdk-servicecatalog (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-ses (1.2.0)
aws-sdk-shield (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-simpledb (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-sms (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-snowball (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-sns (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-sqs (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-ssm (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-states (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-storagegateway (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-support (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-swf (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-v1 (1.67.0)
aws-sdk-waf (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-wafregional (1.1.0)
aws-sdk-workdocs (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-workspaces (1.0.0)
aws-sdk-xray (1.0.0)
aws-sigv2 (1.0.1)
aws-sigv4 (1.0.2)
backports (3.8.0)
bigdecimal (1.3.2, default: 1.3.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.16.0.pre.2, 1.15.4)
capybara (2.15.1)
childprocess (0.7.1)
cliver (0.3.2)
coderay (1.1.2)
common-tools (0.0.6)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
cucumber (2.4.0)
cucumber-core (2.0.0, 1.5.0)
cucumber-wire (0.0.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.3)
did_you_mean (1.1.2, 1.1.0)
diff-lcs (1.3)
domain_name (0.5.20170404)
erubi (1.6.1)
ezlog (0.0.2)
ffi (1.9.18)
gherkin (4.1.3)
globalid (0.4.0)
http-cookie (1.0.3)
i18n (0.8.6)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
jmespath (1.3.1)
**json (default: 2.0.2, 1.8.6)**
kafka-handler (0.1.51)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.6)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_mime (0.1.4)
mini_portile2 (2.3.0, 2.2.0)
minitest (5.10.3, 5.10.1)
mobot (2013.08.1377443804, 0.2.10)
multi_json (1.12.2)
multi_test (0.1.2)
mustermann (1.0.1)
mysql2 (0.4.9)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
netrc (0.11.0)
nio4r (2.1.0)
nokogiri (1.8.1, 1.8.0)
nori (2.6.0)
openssl (default: 2.0.3)
parallel (1.12.0)
parser (2.4.0.0)
poltergeist (1.16.0)
poseidon (0.0.5)
poseidon_cluster (0.3.3, 0.3.0)
power_assert (1.1.0, 0.4.1)
powerpack (0.1.1)
pry (0.10.4)
pry-nav (0.2.4)
pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)
psych (default: 2.2.2)
public_suffix (3.0.0)
rack (2.0.3)
rack-protection (2.0.0)
rack-test (0.7.0)
rails (5.1.4)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.1.4)
rainbow (2.2.2)
rake (12.1.0, 12.0.0)
rdoc (5.1.0, default: 5.0.0)
rest-client (2.0.2)
rspec (3.6.0)
rspec-core (3.6.0)
rspec-expectations (3.6.0)
rspec-mocks (3.6.0)
rspec-support (3.6.0)
rubocop (0.50.0, 0.49.1)
ruby-progressbar (1.8.3)
rubygems-update (2.6.13)
rubyzip (1.2.1)
s3-handler (0.2.5)
selenium-webdriver (3.5.2)
sinatra (2.0.0)
slop (4.5.0, 3.6.0)
sprockets (3.7.1)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
test-unit (3.2.5, 3.2.3)
thor (0.20.0)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tilt (2.0.8)
tomlrb (1.2.4)
tzinfo (1.2.3)
unf (0.1.4)
unf_ext (0.0.7.4)
unicode-display_width (1.3.0)
watir-webdriver (0.9.9)
websocket-driver (0.7.0, 0.6.5)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
xmlrpc (0.3.0, 0.2.1)
xpath (2.1.0)
zk (1.9.6)
zookeeper (1.4.11)
```

My concern is how to remove default tag from the JSON version 2.0.2. Can anyone help me resolve this issue or suggest ways to remove default gem JSON.